# Deploying Tornado on AWS Elastic Beanstalk without WSGI

Tags: python, tornado, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have looked at [Deploying Tornado app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738721/deploying-tornado-app-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

And the solution there was to wrap the app in WSGI wrapper.

Is there anybody who runs a tornado app without the use of WSGI ?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk's standard python platform requires the use of WSGI. You'll need to build a [custom platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html). I'm not aware of any existing platforms that are compatible with tornado, but it should be possible to adapt one of the existing samples (I'd start with the node.js one).